# Problem with synchronous buck converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I’m doing a synchronous buck converter using half bridge driver IR2109 () to step down 200 VDC output from my PFC circuit to around 80VDC. I made a PCB and tested out with Vin = 12 VDC, pulled the (SD) ̅ to high and drove the IN pin by a 100 kHz PWM signal with 50% duty cycle from the Arduino Uno. The board worked fine, and I got a 6 VDC output. Then I tested it with 200 VDC from the PFC, and the traces from the input bulk capacitor to the high side MOSFET, and between the two MOSFET blew up. Both MOSFET were broken as well. So, what was wrong here?
Could it be the fix deadtime in the IR2109 wasn’t enough to protect MOSFET from shoot-through when Vin = 200VDC, even though it worked with Vin = 12VDC?
[image]

Comment: The dead time is 4 us at least, so I don't think that's your problem. But what are the voltage ratings on the other components, C5 in particular?

Comment: You should remove \$C_2\$ which is part of your bootstrap capacitor. It is way too high valued. This cap. should charge in one or two switching cycles when \$Q_2\$ turns on and it has to be of reasonable value. If improperly charged then it may bring an erratic behavior of the upper stage. \$C_3\$ alone is fine. Also, 1k for \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ is way too low and incurs a large useless consumption: increase these two to 47k and it is good enough. I also often recommend to add a small high-value resistance across the DS of \$Q_2\$ to provide a dc link at start-up and immediately charge \$C_3\$.

Comment: Reverse recovery time of 1N400x is really poor (I've seen as high as 30 us).

Comment: 1N4004? As Andy says, throw those out for a start.

Comment: @CharlesB.Cameron C5 rating is 200VDC. I check the rating for all component so that would not be a problem

Comment: @Andyaka  So I need to change diode to the  faster one, like the UF400x?

Comment: @VerbalKint Thanks, I will try this out. And what do you mean by a resistance across DS? Is a like a resistor parallel to source and drain gate of Q2 to the ground to speed up the charge of bootstrap cap?

Comment: One common issue in bootstrapped circuits is the pre-charge of the bootstrap cap. One easy way is to connect a resistor from node UL to GND, offering a dc path to charge the bootstrap cap. at power up. The resistance should be of high value to avoid any useless consumption but the current must be enough to let the bootstrap cap. quickly charge before actuating the bridge. One other option commonly found on HB drivers is to first turn \$Q_2\$ alone for a few ms and charge the cap this way, then, start actuating the bridge afterwards. And yes, better replace the 1N4004 by UF4004 or MUR160.